# how to get comment id in custom_comment_form_submit

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-hooks, drupal-comments

How to get comment id in `comment_form_submit` ?

I built a custom module to send email containing comment details like **comment id**,***url*** and **username**.
But not getting comment id to generate comment url.

```
function custom_comment_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  //code
}
```

Comment: There are so many modules that already do this for you? Any reason why you decided to build your own custom module?

Comment: i want to send mail to a group of users,
this mail will contains complete comment info and link to see comment that's why i need comment id.

Comment: I've added a few suggestions. I still don't really know why you're going the hard way. This is a very simple functionally that it's been added by so many modules.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be to install these two modules. With tokens you will have access to a [list of tokens](http://drupal.org/node/390482) that you can use in your email template, including the comment ID. For a tutorial go here (it's for Drupal 7, but it can be used for Drupal 6 as well): [How to send email notifications for comments in Drupal 7 with actions & triggers (or the Rules module)](http://adellefrank.com/blog/how-to-email-notifications-comments-drupal7)

- [Token](http://drupal.org/project/token)
- [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules)

Not to mention an entire array of already built modules that provide this kind of functionality. Don't waste your time on reinventing the wheel. See this list for a comparison of the available modules: [Comment Notifications comparison](http://groups.drupal.org/node/15928)